# how destructor is functioning when deleting a object of one class in other class

Tags: c++, destructor, delete-operator

In the below code, when deleting a object of base class in destruct class, none of the destructors of any class are getting executed.What may be the reason? Which destructor is "delete obj" calling ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class base;

class destruct{
    public :
    destruct() {
        cout<<"Destruct Constructor called"<<endl;
    }

    void destructObj(base* obj) {
        delete obj;
    }

    ~destruct() {
        cout<<"Destruct Destructor called"<<endl;
    }
};

class base {
    int runs;
    public:

    base(){

        cout<<"Constructor called"<<endl;
    }

    ~base(){
        cout<<"destructor called"<<endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    base *obj = new base();
    destruct *desObj = new destruct();
    desObj->destructObj(obj);
    return 0;
}
```

I expected atleast one of the destructors running of any class.
Please help me find out how the delete operator would be working in this case.

Comment: UB. Your destructor is not virtual. EDIT: ignore that, you're just deleting a `base`. `base`'s destructor is only called, but if you were to pass `desObj` to `destructObj` it would be UB.

Comment: You never `delete` the `desObj` pointer, so that object won't be destructed.

Comment: And it doesn't matter when or where you `delete` the `obj` pointer. In another function or directly in `main`, it will still be deleted just the same. Perhaps the problem you have isn't replicated by the code you show? Is that really a proper [mcve] that replicates the problem you have? What is the output of the program you show? What output did you expect? And please take some time to refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Strange, I think your code should work, but [it doesn't work for me either](https://onlinegdb.com/HkqyAljbr). What am I missing?

Comment: @Neijwiert Despite the class name `base` there's no inheritance here.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This seems like a perfectly good question. I was able to reproduce the OP's problem with exactly the code he gave.

Comment: Clang helpfully produces `warning: deleting pointer to incomplete type 'base' may cause undefined behavior [-Wdelete-incomplete]`.

Comment: @john You're right, I didn't look correctly. Made the assumption too fast :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `destruct::destructObj` needs to see the definition of `Base` to know that there is a destructor to call, but all it has is a forward declaration.

Change your code to this and it works.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class base;

class destruct{
    public :
    destruct() {
        cout<<"Destruct Constructor called"<<endl;
    }

    void destructObj(base* obj);

    ~destruct() {
        cout<<"Destruct Destructor called"<<endl;
    }
};

class base {
    int runs;
    public:

    base(){

        cout<<"Constructor called"<<endl;
    }

    ~base(){
        cout<<"destructor called"<<endl;
    }
};

// *** this function after base has been defined ***
inline void destruct::destructObj(base* obj) {
    delete obj;
}

int main() {
    base *obj = new base();
    destruct *desObj = new destruct();
    desObj->destructObj(obj);
    return 0;
}
```

Now this surprises me and I'm wondering if it's a g++ extension. I would have expected a compiler error when you tried to `delete` a pointer to a class where there is only a forward declaration. But I might be wrong.

UPDATE: apparently this (deleting a pointer to an incomplete class) is *undefined behaviour*, which I guess implies that it should compile. However your compiler really should be giving you a warning to tell you that there's a problem. Always pay attention to compiler warnings, and always compile with the maximum possible number of warnings enabled.

Comment: Thanks john for the great explanation!!.

Comment: Does this mean the delete operator deallocated the memory of obj, But destructor of base class will not execute because of the reason you mentioned?

Comment: @anujbajpai That's clearly what's happening in your case. But all the C++ standard says is that the behaviour is undefined, which means literally anything could happen.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `delete obj` when `obj` is a pointer to an *incomplete* type. This is undefined behaviour (in practice this *usually* means that the destructor is not called, but anything could happen).

You need to move the definition of `base` up where it is visible to the function that calls `delete`.